# C++ The value is never used

Tags: c++

I have a variable `count`. Every time a condition is met, I add one to it. However, it says "the value is never used." However, when I move the variable outside the for loop, it works. Is this a scope issue?

```
for (int i = 0; i < farmers; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    int temp_work_streak;
    if (end_times[i] <= end_times[i + 1] && end_times[i] >= start_times[i + 1]) {
        count++; // the value is never used
    } else {
        temp_work_streak = end_times[i] - start_times[i - count];
        if (temp_work_streak > work_streak) {
            work_streak = temp_work_streak;
        }
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: On an unrelated note, with the code as you currently show it, there's no need for the `continue` statement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you so much! That makes a lot more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is indeed one of scoping.

The variable `count` is local *only inside the loop*, and its life-time is only the current iteration. Each iteration there's a brand new `count` variable. It will not retain its value between iterations of the loop.

The variable is used *either* in `count++` *or* in `i - count`, but not both.

The solution, as you noticed, is to define the variable before the loop starts.